# executing mysql command with password containing especial character inside shell script file

Tags: shell

I have a script that takes username and password as argument.
I store the username and password in a variable
The password is set to 'admin & cd /root & touch hacked &'

```
DBPARAMS="-u $user --password='${password}'"
```

Then I have a command inside script.sh file like this.

```
echo "$sql" | mysql $DBPARAMS --disable-pager -h $dbhost -P $dbport || die "Cannot run mysql"
```

When I run the script with the given password above it failed and it returns the help pager.

But when I try to manually replace $DBPARAMS with the actual value, it passed.

```
echo "$sql" | mysql -u root --password='admin & cd /root & touch hacked &' --disable-pager -h 127.0.0.1 -P 13306 || die "Cannot ru
n mysql"
```

I assume there must be a way of handling especial characters here, but I can't figure out how. I already tried to enclosed the "$DBPARAMS" but it still fail

Comment: probably easiest if the environment MYSQL_PWD= is set to the password leaving it to `mysql` to read that. Eithe that or make DBPARAMS a bash array with a single arg per array element and push use `"${DBPARAM[@]}"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the issue was resolved by adding eval keyword. it worked now

```
echo "$sql" | eval mysql $DBPARAMS --disable-pager -h $dbhost -P $dbport || die "Cannot run mysql"
```

Comment: Yikes. Use this with care and under control.  If your `$DBPARAMS` is hacked with a malicious statement, this could spell trouble. As an alternative, did you try escaping the special characters in the password?